# Getting HTML entities into document.createTextNode

Tags: javascript, string, entities, createtextnode

Suppose I have a string created like this: `str = '\\' + 'u00eb'`. If I do `document.createTextNode(str)`, it will give me '`\u00eb`', instead of `ë`. Dont't ask me why, but I can't define my string as `str = '\u00eb'`. Defining my string as `str = '&euml;'` or `'&amp;euml;'` doesn't help me either. Any suggestions on how to get `'ë'` printed?

Comment: Why can't you define it as `str = '\u00eb'`?

Comment: One possibility is `var s = eval('"\\' + 'u00eb"');`. I know you said to not ask why, but I am curious why you can't use the proper escape sequence directly in your code

Comment: `str = '\' + 'u00eb'` is a syntax error.

Comment: I cannot write '\u00eb' directly, since I get the string from an XML file using XMLHttpRequest, over which I have limited control.

Comment: @PieterN then you're going to have to interpret the numeric value with your own code and then use `String.fromCharCode()` to build the string.

Comment: You're right about the syntax error, it should be '\\' + 'u00eb'!

Comment: @PieterN: Thanks. So the XML just returns the `u00eb` part. Perhaps better than `eval` would be `var s = new Function('return "\\' + 'u00eb' + '";')();`

Comment: I'll try both the eval and the new Function methods.

Comment: My strings can be something like 'This is a tëst', I have them converted now using something like str =  eval('"' + str + '"'). I just have to be sure '"' is not part of the original str.

Comment: I don't understand. If that's your string, it already has the proper unicode character, so there should be no need for an escape sequence.

Comment: I should be more specific: my string 'This is a tëst' will be received as 'This is a t\u00ebst'.

Comment: @PieterN: Alright, then the solutions I gave above should work. If you want something a little safer, then you could use `JSON.parse()` instead. `var s = JSON.parse('"' + 'This is a t\u00ebst' + '"');`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
var str = String.fromCharCode(0xeb);
```

Comment: That should work, if it would always be 0xeb that I want to translate. Unfortunately, str can contain all kinds of characters... Sorry about my unclear questioning

Comment: @PieterN well as I said in the comment to your question, you'll have to write code to detect character code values in your XML, interpret them as numeric values, and then construct the string. You have not provided a sample of what your XML actually looks like, so it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If the data coming in looks like this:

```
u00eb
```

then, you can parse the hex string yourself:

```
function insertText(parent, str) {
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'u') {
        str = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str.slice(1), 16));
    }
    parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pk5Bp/